# Command Line Interface Scala

Tags: scala, command-line, command-line-interface

So I'm trying to build a command line interface for my scala project,
however, there are many examples online, but not much explanation to how they work etc, i really don't need anything complex.

All i need to be able to do in the command is to allow an input of a file path to the file and an input for the output directory.

Can any help me out and give me an example tell me how it works etc?

Answer (score 0):

For something simple, pattern matching can be sufficient.

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = args.toList match {
  case in :: out :: _ => println(s"OK: $in -> $out")
  case _ => println(s"Invalid arguments: $args")
}
```

Comment: Hi so i tried using your method of pattern matching,  however, when i tried the input     $ sbt run /Users/myName/Desktop/Projectj/proj/test.java  /Users/myName/Desktop    i got an error saying that "/" is an invalid input, i also tried putting the two file paths into speech marks but it still didnt work

Comment: To get access to cmd args you need to extend App
`object Foo extends App { \\here you can use arg }` like here https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-shell-script-command-line-arguments-args/

Answer (score 0):

I once did something similar (read arguments from CLI - https://github.com/pedrorijo91/euromillions-generator)

I used Argot: https://github.com/bmc/argot
but it seems it's deprecated and they recommend to use Scopt: https://github.com/scopt/scopt

Answer (score 0):

```
object Main extends App {
  args.toList match {
    case in :: out :: _ => println(s"OK: $in -> $out")
    case _ => println(s"Invalid arguments: $args")
  }
}
```